# How do i get a Picture bigger than the box arround it without deforming everything?

Tags: html, css

i have a project at school where im trying to make a flashgames website but im stuck with a problem.I want the picture be bigger than the gray box.The picture how i want it : https://prntscr.com/frvzyy

My html Code:

```css
    *{
     margin: 0px;
     background-color:darkred;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-left: 30%;
        padding-right: 30%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    
    li {
        float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
        display: block;
        font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
     background-color: darkred;
    }
    #logo {
        display: block;
        font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }   
    
    li a:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }
    
    }
    p{font-family:Tahoma;}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Games</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
    </head>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1vs1 Games</a></li>
            <li id="logo"><img src="src/flash%20games%20logo.png" style="width:250px;"></li>
            <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
      
        </ul>
        <h1>Games</h1>
        <p>content bla bla</p>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. **What image & what grey box?** How is this supposed to look?

Comment: Also, Flash? I don't see Flash anywhere, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Mention width and height for that image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes to achieve this.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color:darkred;
}
.nav{
    height: 100px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding-left: 30%;
    padding-right: 30%;*/
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background-color: gray;
    height: 48px;
}

li {
    /*float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 -2px;

}

li a {
    display: block;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: darkred;
}
#logo {
    /*display: block;*/
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}   
#logo img{
    display: block;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

}
p{font-family:Tahoma;}
```

```html
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1vs1 Games</a></li>
            <li id="logo"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/94/77/f9/9477f98e6d5154911c05467c4acb24c5.jpg" style="width:250px;"></li>
            <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h1>Games</h1>
    <p>content bla bla</p>
```

I hope it will helps you :)

Comment: thank you so much. the gif looks awesome in there too xD. im thinking if will keep it. thanks again, this really helps alot.

Comment: It's all my pleasure :)